# how can i check if a proxy is alive or not in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm creating a 'bot' opening a page with random proxies obtained from a file.txt, but i wanna check first if the proxy is alive or not before using them.

I'm not going to put any code here because I am only doing a request if somebody have a simple method to do this task.

I read about `InetSocketAddress` but I have the problem that I can only use it with `(String Host, Int port)`. How can I pass *Host+port* together in a simple String?

If this is not the solution, can someone explain me another method?

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass the `host:port` as a single string?

Comment: Because it comes directly from a file txt like an string with host and port together: 657.56.348.23:8080

Comment: And the problem with separating it into two parameters is what?

Comment: That i have to read from two file and these do not synchronize At same time.

Answer (score 1):

> I read about "InetSocketAddress" ...

If you are going to test the proxy, this is one approach.  (Just test that you can open a TCP/IP connection to the proxy, and then close it).  Another way would be to set up your own tiny webserver with a text page, and test the proxy by using it to access your test page.  (That gives a more accurate "read" on the liveness of a proxy.)

> ... but i have the problem that only can i (String Host, Int port) how can i pass Host+port in a simple String?

That is easy.  You don't.

You need to parse the string and extract the hostname and the port number.  (Java 101 stuff ...) Then pass you pass them as separate arguments.

If the "string" is actually a URL or URI, then you can use `java.net.URI` to do the parsing.

---

However, there's another approach.  Don't test the proxy.  Just use it, and if it doesn't respond then mark it as bad.

IMO, you pretty much have to adopt this approach to make your code robust.  If you probe a proxy and find it to be reachable and working at time T, there is no guarantee that it will still be working at time T + 1.  No amount of testing will solve that.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is invalid.

The only viable way to test whether *any* resource is available is to try to use it in the normal course of your program, and handle the errors if it fails.

Otherwise you're involved in predicting the future. It might be up when you test and down when you use. Or the other way around. Or you might test it in a different way from how you will use it, and so, again, get a different result.